# Python sockets & Opencv - ConnectionResetError: [WinError 10054]

Tags: python, python-3.x, sockets, opencv, networking

Edit: To clarify: it does compile, it just crashes almost immediately after the stream loads. **It does connect properly.**

So, I've been trying for a very long time to complete this project of mine. What I'm trying to do is send a video feed over sockets using cv2. It works over LAN, not over WAN. I get the following error:

> "ConnectionResetError: [WinError 10054] An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host"

**Code for client(sending video over):**

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import socket
import pickle

host = "<insert public ip of recipient>"
port = 7643

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)  # declares s object with two parameters
s.connect((host, port))  # connects to the host & port
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(1)
while cap.isOpened(): # while camera is being used
    ret, frame = cap.read()  # reads each frame from webcam
    if ret:
        encoded = pickle.dumps(cv2.imencode(".jpg", frame)[1]) # encoding each frame, instead of sending live video it is sending pictures one by one
        s.sendall(encoded)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord("q"): # wait until key was pressed once and
        break
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

**Code for recipient(receiving video):**

```
import cv2
import socket
import pickle

host = "192.168.1.186"
port = 7643
boo = True

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)  # declares s object with two parameters
s.bind((host, port))  # tells my socket object to connect to this host & port "binds it to it"
s.listen(10)  # tells the socket how much data it will be receiving.

conn, addr = s.accept()
while boo:
    try:
        pictures = conn.recv(256000)  # creates a pictures variable that receives the pictures with a max amount of 128000 data it can receive
        decoded = pickle.loads(pictures)  # decodes the pictures
        frame = cv2.imdecode(decoded, cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)  # translates decoded into frames that we can see!
        cv2.imshow("unique", frame)
        if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord("q"):  # wait until q key was pressed once and
            break
    except:
        print("Something is broken...")
        boo = False
        cv2.destroyAllWindows()
        s.close()
```

Comment: Your recipient is running on a LAN with NAT. Have you forwarded the correct port from the router to the recipient?

Comment: Uh I don't know exactly what NAT means, but we did forward ports. The window pops open and streams my camera for a split second before it crashes and outputs that error which was in the title of the question.

Answer (score 3):

You apparently got lucky when running this over your LAN. Your code is not correctly sending a stream of images from sender to recipient, because stream sockets like TCP are a little more complicated to use by their nature. The main issue is that **your sender is not communicating where each image ends and the next begins, and your recipient similarly is not organizing the data it reads into individual full images.**

That is to say, `socket.sendall()` does not communicate the end of its data to the recipient; you need to include that information in the actual data that you send.

## Error handling

But before fixing that, you should fix your error handling on the recipient so that you get more useful error messages. When you write

```
except:
    print("Something is broken...")
```

You're throwing away something that would have helped you more, like "EOFError: Ran out of input" or "_pickle.UnpicklingError". Don't throw that information away. Instead, print it:

```
except:
    traceback.print_exc()
```

or re-raise it:

```
except Exception as err:
    # do whatever you want to do first
    raise err
```

or, since you want to let it crash your program, and just want to do cleanup first, do your cleanup in a `finally` clause, no need for `except`:

```
try:
    # your code
finally:
    # the cleanup
```

## Stream sockets and the sender

Back to your socket code, you're using stream sockets. They send a stream of bytes, and while you can count on them arriving in the correct order, you can't count on when they'll arrive. If you send `b"something"` and then `b"something else"`, you could receive `b"somethingsomething else"` all at once, `b"somet"` and then later `b"hing"`, etc. Your receiver needs to know where the dividing line is between each message, so step one is making there *be* dividing lines between the messages. There are a few ways to do this:

- Making all messages be the same size. Since you're encoding them as JPEGs which can have different sizes based on how it's compressed, that would be a little complicated and maybe not what you want anyway.
- Sending an actual marker in bytes, like a newline `b"\n"` or `b"\n\r"`. This is more complicated to make work for your situation.
- Sending the size of each message before you send it. This should be the easiest for your case.

Of course if you're now sending the size of the message, that's just like another message, and your recipient needs to know where this size message ends. Once again you could end the size message with a newline:

```
s.sendall("{}\n".format(len(encoded)).encode("ascii"))
```

Or you could pack it into a fixed-length number of bytes, for example 4:

```
s.sendall(struct.pack("!i", len(encoded)))
```

## The receiver

Your receiver code now needs to read full messages, despite the fact that `socket.recv()` can return partial messages, or parts of multiple messages together. You can keep a buffer of the incoming data. Add to the end, and then remove full messages from the front:

```
buf = ''
while boo:
    new_data = s.recv(4096)
    if not new_data:
      # exit, because the socket has been closed
    buf += new_data
  # if there's a full message at the beginning of buf:
  #     remove that message, but leave the rest in buf
  #     process that message
  # else:
  #     nothing, just go back to receiving more
```

Of course, to find your full message, first you need to get the full size message. If you encoded all your size messages as 4 bytes with `struct.pack`, just receive data until `buf` is 4 or more bytes long, then split it into the size and any remaining data:

```
message_size = struct.unpack("!i", buf[:4])[0]
buf = buf[4:]
```

Then do the same thing with the image message. Receive data until you have at least `message_size` bytes of data, split your buffer into the first image message, which you can decode and display, and keep the remainder in the buffer.

## Security

The [documentation for `pickle`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html) says:

> **Warning:** The `pickle` module **is not secure**. Only unpickle data you trust.
>   It is possible to construct malicious pickle data which will **execute arbitrary code during unpickling**. Never unpickle data that could have come from an untrusted source, or that could have been tampered with.

In your case, someone else could in theory connect to your IP on your chosen port and send whatever they wanted to your recipient. If this is just a toy project that wouldn't be left running all the time, the odds are low.

Comment: Thanks. I'll try that and let you know if it works.